# Either open mutliple web URLs or disable the button on specific condition

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have two columns: one with the names of the routes, and the other with the URLs for each of the routes. In BI dashboard, I have inserted a slicer for route names and a button to redirect to URLs for selected route in slicer (with help of action tab, Type- web url, and conditional formatting). So if I choose a route in the slicer and click on button, I'm taken to that Web address.

What i want is, if i select multiple routes in my slicer then it should open multiple web urls (I guess this is not possible). Or If I select more than one route in slicer, the button should be disabled so that it cannot be clicked. It should work only if i select single route in slicer.
Is there any way to do this?